# How to simulate printing 10K duplex sheets without wasting paper and ink

Tags: vb.net, printing

We have a desktop app written in VB.NET that prints 10K duplex reports once a month. There is a problem that we need to debug or try to replicate.

If I print to a NULL printer, it works fine.

How can I realistically simulate printing all these sheets of paper without actually printing?

Comment: Using a PDF printer may be a good solution. Another way may be using a normal printer but set it to print to a file (in windows is pretty easy)

Comment: I've tried CutePDF but that needs a filename for each report. Do you know of one that will just churn them out with a random filename?

Comment: Sorry but no, each print job will need a different file name (in my experience). Maybe you can supply a filename at runtime hijacking the PrintDialog, but I've never tried it. Using a normal driver and setting it to print to a file probably has the very same limitations.

Comment: check this http://www.novapdf.com/kb/how-to-create-a-pdf-file-without-displaying-the-save-pdf-file-as-dialog-140.html or this http://superuser.com/questions/103855/pdf-printer-without-user-intervention

Comment: BigMike, you should put your answers in the answers box so we can upvote you properly (and mark as answer if it is the answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recap of my comments, as OP requested,

Using a PDF printer may be a good solution. Another way may be using a normal printer but set it to print to a file (in windows is pretty easy).

The main drawback would be giving a file name to each print job, maybe you can supply a filename at runtime hijacking the PrintDialog, but I've never tried it. Using a normal driver and setting it to print to a file probably has the very same limitations.

However there are a couple of PDF printing drivers which support automatic naming, check [this link](http://www.novapdf.com/kb/how-to-create-a-pdf-file-without-displaying-the-save-pdf-file-as-dialog-140.html) or [this question on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/103855/pdf-printer-without-user-intervention)

Answer (score 2):

Using CutePDF to print to a PDF file with a sequentially generated file name (and directory if required) should be able to duplicate the problem.

However if the problem is in the printer driver and not your code then printing to PDF won't find the problem. It might be nice to get details of the exact problem that's occurring.

Comment: There are many variables. Our client has a very flaky network, the computer our client uses is poor and the printer itself seems a bit dodgy too. At first it looks like an out of memory exception, but does not happen when printing to a NULL printer. We thought it might be leaving word open (it creates some letters in Word while using SSRS for most of the reports)  but it isn't. They leave it running through the night, but the problem can occur after a few minutes or a few hours. Maybe there's several issues here - network dropping, print spool service stopping, etc.

Comment: We're just trying to realistically create the conditions our client experiences to see if we can get it to happen.

Comment: If the problem doesn't occur except under very specific circumstances then you may be in trouble. Using PDf printing may not resolve the issue as the problem could be anywhere